# tres en raya java

Tags: java, poo, eclipse

Estoy haciendo la comprobacion de las diagonales y en el `if` pongo la posicion correcta pero se ejecuta con cualquier posicion de `i` y de `j`:

Este metodo busca por el `array[][]` y si encuentra la x en la posicion que le indico suma 1 al contador,
el problema es que entra dentro del `if` sea cuales sean la `i` y la `j` y aunque no hay "X"

```
   public static int comprobarDiagonales(String[][] aux) {
        
        int contador = 0; // Contador para X
        
        int contador1 = 0; // Contador para O
        
        int max = 0; // Busca el mayor
        
        for (int i = 0; i < aux.length; i++) {
            
            for (int j = 0; j < aux[i].length; j++) {
                    
                if ((aux[0][0].equals("X") || aux[1][1].equals("X") || aux[2][2].equals("X")) { 
                    
                    contador++;
                                                            
                } else if ((aux[0][0].equals("O") || aux[1][1].equals("O") || aux[2][2].equals("O"))) {
                    
                    contador1++;
            
                }
                
                if (contador > contador1) {
                    
                    max = contador;
                    
                } else {
                    
                    max = contador1;
                }
            
            }
            
        }
        
        return max;
    }
```

El auxiliar que recibe es el tablero con las posiciones de las fichas

Este es el metodo principal:

```
    private void jugar() {

        boolean[][] ocupada = new boolean[filas][columnas];     

        for (int i = 0; i < tablero.length; i++) {

            for (int j = 0; j < tablero[i].length; j++) {

                if (Coordenada.comprobarFilas(tablero) < 3) {

                    if (Coordenada.comprobarColumnas(tablero) < 3) {

                        if (Coordenada.comprobarDiagonales(tablero) < 3) {

                            //                  System.out.println(Coordenada.comprobarFilas(tablero) + " " + Coordenada.comprobarColumnas(tablero));

                            System.out.println();

                            Coordenada.leerCoordenada();

                            if (!ocupada[Coordenada.getFila()][Coordenada.getColumna()]) {

                                tablero[Coordenada.getFila()][Coordenada.getColumna()] = colocarFicha() + "";

                                ocupada[Coordenada.getFila()][Coordenada.getColumna()] = true;

                                for (int j2 = 0; j2 < tablero.length; j2++) {

                                    for (int k = 0; k < tablero[j2].length; k++) {

                                        System.out.print(tablero[j2][k] + " ");
                                    }

                                    System.out.println();
                                }

                                cambiarTurno();

                            } else {

                                System.out.println("La posicion (" + Coordenada.getFila() + ", " + Coordenada.getColumna() + ") ya esta ocupada");

                            }


                        } 

                        //                  System.out.println("Ha ganado el jugador " + this.turno);





                        //                  break;
                        //              System.out.println("Ha ganado el jugador " + this.turno);




                    } 
                }

            }

        } 

        System.out.println("Ha ganado el jugador " + this.turno);


    }
```

A ver si me podeis echar un cable gracias.

Answer (score 0):

el problema es que usas || (OR) en la condifición if en lugar de && (AND). No obstante yo comprobaría si hay un tres en raya de la siguiente forma, el parámetro strTurno que añado a la función sería "X" o "O" dependiendo del jugador actual y la función devolvería verdadero si hay un ganador y falso si no:

```
public static boolean comprobarSiHayGanador(String strTurno, String[][] aux) {
    
    // Comprueba diagonal a la derecha
    if ( aux[0][0].equals(strTurno) && 
         aux[1][1].equals(strTurno) && 
         aux[2][2].equals(strTurno) ) return true;
    // Comprueba diagonal a la izquierda
    if ( aux[0][2].equals(strTurno) && 
         aux[1][1].equals(strTurno) && 
         aux[2][0].equals(strTurno) ) return true;
         
    // Comprueba filas y columnas
    for(int i=0; i < 3: i++)
    {
        // Comprueba filas
        if ( aux[i][0].equals(strTurno) && 
             aux[i][1].equals(strTurno) && 
             aux[i][2].equals(strTurno) ) return true;
        // Comprueba columnas
        if ( aux[0][i].equals(strTurno) && 
             aux[1][i].equals(strTurno) && 
             aux[2][i].equals(strTurno) ) return true;
    }
    
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por la ayuda

Comment: Si la respuesta te fue de ayuda y sirvió para solucionar tu problema estaría bien que la marcaras como correcta. Más que nada porque cuando se formula una pregunta ya sea esta u otras a futuro hay personas que dedican su tiempo a responderte.